# Is it bad practice to overload a function to take both a pointer or a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading

For example, if I had a struct `FooSpec`:

```
struct FooSpec { /* lots of data */ };
```

Is it bad practice to provide *both* of the following as overloaded functions? Or should I just choose one and stick with it?

```
Foo *createFoo(const FooSpec *spec) { /* ... */ }
Foo *createFoo(const FooSpec &spec) { return createFoo(&spec); }
```

Could having both cause unexpected problems?

Comment: You shouldn't have any *tecnhical* problem, but I would certainly be puzzled seeing an API like this.

Comment: If one function just calls the other, what benefit would an inconsistent interface provide?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Well I mean things like inducing human error.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that `const` keyword...^-^;

Comment: If you're reserving the option of passing `nullptr`, a pointer version is warranted and the reference version is add-complexity for the convenience of some client author avoiding typing an ampersand `&`. If NULL is not an option then the reference version is the right approach and the pointer version is similar added-complexity, this time to avoid typing an asterisk `*`. In either case there is no *tangible* benefit and both are done at the expense of added complexity. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. Pick the appropriate model and tell the clients "this is your interface."

Comment: @zenith that's the clearest answer so far.  You should promote it to a proper answer.

Comment: OK, it's not bad practice if you're in the process of migrating your coding convention to use references instead of `const *` (or the opposite, but that doesn't make much sense to me).

Comment: @WhozCraig: You should make that comment into an answer.

Comment: @Matt zenith's is sufficient (and uptick accordingly). And I should have mentioned, if `nullptr` is *not* an option providing a mechanism for someone to do so *at all* is a terrible idea; further furnace embers this idea should be squelched.

Comment: I prefer to avoid _any_ kind of syntactic overloading, so imagine what I think about this one.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: Do you also avoid default arguments?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I do, but with a bit less of emphasys.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There should be only one way to do a specific thing. This will make the code clearer for its users. Therefore, you should pick only one, depending on the semantics:

- If a `nullptr` is a meaningful value to be passed to `createFoo`, then declare the function to take a pointer.
- If a `nullptr` shouldn't be passed to `createFoo`, then declare the parameter a reference to make the compiler yell at people who try pass in a `nullptr`.

Now the users of your code will go "Ah, I can pass a null to that function, cool!" or "Okay this function needs an actual object to work properly".

Stick to this convention throughout a project to make the interface of the code more coherent.

Or as [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) put it,

> Pick the appropriate model and tell the clients "this is your interface."

Comment: One could say, "if the object must exist, pass by reference", this means that the function doesn't have to worry about invalid pointer values and testing of them.

Comment: Also, a `nullptr` should have a meaning to your function. For example: if you get `nullptr` and `throw invalid_argument`, it's meaningless. Imposing a reference is much better in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of one marginally useful reason to do this.

The `Foo*` version can check for null, handle that case, and if not use the reference case.

The `Foo&` can then not check for null.

This lets callers say "I know this is not null because I checked", saving a branch within the function.

However this benefit (saving a branch) is pointless once the cost of the method passes a very low threshhold.

Answer (score 3):

A software codebase is not a static object, it evolves<sup>†</sup> with the needs of those who use it. If a confusing interface is "bad practice" (I would rather say a silly thing to do), a codebase may end up in such situation as it evolves from refactoring and code improvement.

In this instance, it's not bad practice if you're in the process of migrating your coding conventions to use references instead of const pointers (or the opposite, but that doesn't make much sense to me). The bad practice here would probably to make these evolutions and not document it, with other people not knowing that one of these methods is deprecated, or simply which one to use.

There's also the possibility of passing a `nullptr_t` (or `NULL` pointers for old timers like me) With const pointers. I am not sure of the benefit of this, given that you can overload methods on their arguments, but again in the context of a changing API it makes sense.

---

<sup>† it's alive!!!</sup>

Comment: So you would say that an interface should not be designed this way from the start?

Comment: @Matt It probably should not, but I'm sure someone would eventually come up with a good reason for doing so. Do you know a good reason for it?

Comment: As @WhozCraig put it in his comment, my reasons were simply avoiding typing an extra `&` or `*`. I guess that's not really a "good" reason.

Comment: Don't favor conciseness over clarity (though I admit I don't follow it enough myself).